# Blank page in IE8 and 9

Tags: meteor, meteorite

I've recently built and launched this page: http://www.thaiestatenetwork.com

It works great in Chrome, Safari, Firefox and even IE10, but in IE8 and 9 all I get is a blank page.

I've read through post here on SO about similar issues and based on that I've tried this:

- going over my templates in an attempt to find DOM errors.
- Tried setting position:static on html and body
- commented out @font-face in my CSS (since I was getting an error in IE on BrowserStack related to @font-face)
- Checked for potential CORS issues. Found none.

None of it works.

Strangely too, when I tunnel to my local dev machine through BrowserStack, everything works like a charm.

I should add that the site is built using router https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router and runs on Heroku using this build pack: https://github.com/oortcloud/heroku-buildpack-meteorite

I really hope someone out there has that fresh pair of eyes that will lead me on the right track.

Comment: I should also mention that if I activate the debug panel in IE and update the page, then everything works as intended.

Comment: I've had the same problems using the Router package, though I've never looked deeper into the problem (didn't need IE8-9 in those projects).

My only advice really is to test often and early in IE8-9.

Comment: Just seems strange that it works when I tunnel to my dev machine (admittedly running in non-minified mode) but not in production mode. I guess I might have to take a look at alternatives to router...

Comment: The router does work in IE8-9 though, just treat it gently (and test often!) :)

Comment: I'm using it here for example: http://www.tweedbar.se/swedish/

Not much routing going on overall, but the routing that does go on works in IE8.

Comment: @KristofferK Tweed looks super cool. Gotta stop by next time I'm in Stockholm :-)

Comment: @KristofferK I have solved my issue, and I will post the solution in a sec, but on a related note: how did you manage to get the GA script into the head section of http://tweedbar.se/swedish?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27164/discussion-between-madsmao-and-kristoffer-k)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved it!

The issue turned out to be related to the way I was initializing Google Analytics (GA). I was doing this:

```
Template.menu.created = function() {
  // GA initialization code here
};
```

I had to do this:

```
Template.menu.rendered = function() {
  if ( typeof ga === 'undefined' ) {
    // GA initialization code here
  }
};
```

So basically I was attempting to initialise GA on first creation of my menu template, but instead I had to latch on to the `rendered` callback and add a conditional to make sure I only initialise GA once.

Overall I am not thrilled with my approach to initialising GA, but that is another matter entirely. It works.

Comment: You should probably append the GA code to the `<head>` of your document as is standard practice. This is pretty janky. In the root of your project create a base doc with `head` and `body` tags and do it there. Meteor searches your project for instances of HTML `head` tags and uses that for your base doc.